# How can I get the current placepicker location?

Tags: jquery, gmsplacepicker

I want to alert the selected location but it is not alerting anything:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="placepicker form-control" data-map-container-id="collapseOne"/>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse">
  <div class="placepicker-map thumbnail"></div>
</div>



 var mapPlacepicker = $(".placepicker").placepicker();


 $(".placepicker").each(function() {
      var target = this;
         var $collapse = $(this).parents('.form-group').next('.collapse');
         var $map = $collapse.find('.another-map-class');
         var placepicker = $(this).placepicker({
             map: $map.get(0),
             placeChanged: function(place) {
                  alert("place changed: ", place.formatted_address, this.getLocation());
             }
        }).data('placepicker');
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vfgv7dtz/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the code of placeChanged within you placepicker initialization

like this

```
 var mapPlacepicker = $(".placepicker").placepicker({placeChanged: function(place) {

                  alert("place changed: "+ place.formatted_address +" Latitude" +this.getLocation().latitude + " Longitude" + this.getLocation().longitude);
             }});
```

here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vfgv7dtz/5/